# Why does NLog miss some messages when logging a large number of messages?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I try to test NLog performance (latest version) with settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
    <variable name="basePath" value="c:\logs\" />
    <variable name="msgFormat" value="${message}" />
    <targets async="true">
        <target name="file"
                xsi:type="File"
                fileName="${basePath}/${logger}/${date:format=yyyy}/${date:format=MMMM}/log-${date:format=yyMMdd}-${level}.log"
                layout="${msgFormat}"
                concurrentWrites="true" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

and run this code:

```
var msg = "this is example string for logging test. it's not very long, but not very short";
var count = 20000;
Parallel.For(0, count, x => nlog.Info(msg));
```

NLog writes to file, but when file size reaches 1MB it stops writing. I try to use simple `for` loop, but it doesn't helped me.
And i try to use [internal logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging), but there is no errors, by the way i see there this strings:

> 2013-04-01 11:36:18.2458 Trace Opening
>   c:\logs/NLogTest/2013/April/log-130401-Info.log with
>   concurrentWrite=False

It's very strange, because [concurrentWrites](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#performance-tuning-options) default value is `true`, furthermore I've set this value in config.

Comment: Is it any different if you try it in a single thread instead of parallelism? [edit]Never mind you wrote that allready.

Comment: There is no difference with single thread — when file gets 1MB size it stops appending to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the default value of the `AsyncWrapper`s `QueueLimit`, which is 10000.

The value determines how big the queue of messages to write are allowed to be, the problem arises because all 20000 messages are queued before anything is written to the file, which causes NLog to discard the last 10000 messages.

Unfortunately this cannot be changed when using the `async` attribute, you have to define the `AsyncWrapper` manually to be able to control the `QueueLimit`, which is done like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
    <variable name="basePath" value="c:\logs\" />
    <variable name="msgFormat" value="${message}" />
    <targets async>
        <target name="asyncWrapper" xsi:Type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="20000">
            <target name="file"
                xsi:type="File"
                fileName="${basePath}/${logger}/${date:format=yyyy}/${date:format=MMMM}/log-${date:format=yyMMdd}-${level}.log"
                layout="${msgFormat}"
                concurrentWrites="true" />
       </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Where QueueLimit is set to 20000.

You could also changed the `OverflowAction` if you need to do something other the discard messages not put in the queue, see [AsyncWrapper](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target) documentation for more information. The options are Block, Discard or Grow.

Comment: in Nlog documentation, it mentioned
Don't combine the Async attribute and AsyncWrapper. This will only slow down processing and will behave unreliably. So seem like in your sample code, it is better to remove the async attribute? 
https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target#async-attribute-and-asyncwrapper